# Exception while using @EnableScheduling in springboot: Unable to make protected java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting an error regarding accessibility issue while running the application.

The `decorateTask()` method is a protected method of the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor class, which means it can only be accessed by subclasses of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, or by other classes in the same package as `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. If you are not accessing the method from a subclass or from the same package, you will need to modify your code to either extend `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` or move your code into the same package as `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

Here is my springboot version:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

This is my java version and the spring cloud version:

```
<java.version>17</java.version>
<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
```

I am getting this exception while executing it.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.task.TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.decorateTask(java.lang.Runnable,java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util.concurrent" to unnamed module @525b461a
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at io.armadillo.aftfileuploads.AftFileUploadsApplication.main(AftFileUploadsApplication.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.decorateTask(java.lang.Runnable,java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util.concurrent" to unnamed module @525b461a
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:577)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.LazyTraceScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.makeAccessibleIfNotNull(LazyTraceScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.LazyTraceScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(LazyTraceScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.LazyTraceThreadPoolTaskScheduler.getScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(LazyTraceThreadPoolTaskScheduler.java:181)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.ExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExecutorBeanPostProcessor.java:356)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$19449eea.getScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.task.TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration.safeGetThreadPoolExecutor(TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.task.TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration.lambda$bindTaskExecutorsToRegistry$0(TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration.java:61)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.task.TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration.bindTaskExecutorsToRegistry(TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:724)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This solved the issue:**

Issue with using schedular in Spring cloud. It has different configuration:
reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-sleuth-single-application

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class ThreadConfig extends AsyncConfigurerSupport
  implements SchedulingConfigurer {
 
    //...
    
    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setScheduler(schedulingExecutor());
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown") // I had to remove this line. because it gives error
    public Executor schedulingExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    }
}
```

So, in my case proper dependency was not taken and during autoconfiguration it was giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution when you are running the application locally, put the below java options under Run as -->run configurations->arguments-->VM arguments.

```
--add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

For remote `/server` running in my case, as we are using Kubernetes, in values.yaml file I have added below

```
name: JAVA_OPTS
value: " --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED"
```